# What kind of neural network would solve classification of simple dataset

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I decided to fit simple data, the rgb images of shape (w, h, 3) to cifar-10 neural network with 128 classes. For class number N I generated same images all filled with N value in all 3 channels. 
So, class 1 data = set of the same images filled with 1, class 2 - filled with 2 and so on.

Running cifar-10 with original dataset worked fine, but as soon as I changed the data to my generated data the training stuck at 0% of train accuracy, loss fluctuates around 4.xx value.

I want to know what kind of neural network would solve classification problem such simple dataset?

I came up with this because I decided to use cifar for one project with rgb images, where the images contain 9 light sources (9 circles) and different class images are almost similar to each other but the intensity at some light sources might be different , the maximum pixelwise absolute difference between images of different classes is equal to 25 (rgb image pixel values range is from 0 to 255). I thought it might be too small and network is training on noise, and decided to check how would cifar behave on the data with very small changes (rgb filled with unique constant value for each class).

Now I'm more interested in why such simple dataset can't be trained by cifar, 
cifar code taken from:

https://github.com/exelban/tensorflow-cifar-10

The only things changed in that code are the data loading, changing number of classes to 128 and fixing the input image sizes to a new values. Plus I changed the convolutional layer kernel sizes. At least I expected some overfitting with bad generalization. But not zero % accuracy.

Comment: Any algorithm should lern the difference. Are you sure you don't have any bugs in the code? or maybe you have some problems in your labels? Also, when you say "0% accuracy", does it mean that your prediction is random, but accuracy not exactly zero?

Comment: @itdxer I'm sure that the network is correct in code. If I feed cat/dogs/animals images it works fine. When I feed my data it works not good, zero accuracy meaning that the prediction is always the same, softmax gives the vector with zeros and one at the same place. Well in average it is something like 0.78% out of 100% accuracy (in one epoch).

Comment: @itdxer Interesting thing, after trying the same data and simple network on matlab, it's GUI showed that there is some preprocessing of images being done. Then training started and showed excellent results. I wonder what matlab did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried gradient descent optimizer and Adam optimizer in tensorflow. But then in Matlab I tried stochastic gradient descent with momentum. Amazingly it did the work, also I tried Adam optimizer at matlab and got the same issue. 
Which tells me that the issue was in optimizer.